# Remove amount of lines above and below a line containing a string

Tags: python, python-2.5

I'm formatting GPS output logs and I need an efficient method to remove x number of lines above the line that contains a 0 and y number of lines below that line.

```
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 0
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
*--------------------------------------*
```

If the line contains "Position fix ind: 0", remove 6 lines above it and remove 3 lines below in and remove the line it is in

EDIT:

The input file is a .log file

EDIT 2:

input file

```
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 0
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
 *--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 5
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
*--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
```

Comment: So you want to remove both the delimiting lines? Shouldn't you just remove one?

Comment: you want to just get that line or save it in a file after you have deleted the lines above/below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def remLines(infilepath, outfilepath, delim, above, below):
    infile = open(infilepath)
    outfile = open(outfilepath, 'w')
    buff = []
    line = infile.readline()
    while line:
        if line.strip() == delim:
             buff = []
             for _ in range(below): # need to error check here, if you're not certain that your input file is correctly formatted
                 infile.readline()
        else:
            if len(buff) == above:
                outfile.write(buff[0])
                buff = buff[1:]
            buff.append(line)
        line = infile.readline()
    outfile.write(''.join(buff))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    remLines('path/to/input', 'path/to/output', "Position fix ind: 0", 6,3)
```

**Testing**:

Input:

```
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 0
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
 *--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 5
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
*--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 5
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
*--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
```

Comment: If you're familiar with other programming languages like Java or C, you know that there's a special function called `main`, which gets executed first. Similarly, if you run a python file with `if __name__ == "__main__":`, the code in that scope is what is executed first

Comment: The code works but it only deletes the row with "Position fix ind: 0" and leaves the rest alone

Comment: It has the error that all digits not in the starred area and also letters are excluded and everything else is erased. input file is at: http://www.mediafire.com/download/07y2xpn8xvm81vj/input.txt

MD5: 6e473af83165e3004dcc19280d783126
SHA1: c37d8078ad8cd146ae8074ce9b75409ff1e26b34

Comment: I just ran this code against your input file. I got what I think is the expected output. I need a more detailed explanation as to how the observed output differs from the expected

Comment: My output turns out to be empty

Comment: That's strange! I got two blocks of delimited data in my output, when I ran it on the file you linked. Are you sure you have the correct file paths? If so, have you tried step-through debugging to see where it's dying? I don't have a python2.5 install, or I would do it myself

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` here, iterate over the file and as soon as you see `'Position fix ind: 0'` in a line(say, index  of the line is `i`), then add a set of numbers from `i-6` to `i+3`
to a set.

```
f = open('abc')
se = set()
for i,x in enumerate(f):
    if 'Position fix ind: 0' in x:
        se.update(range(i-6,i+4))
f.close()
```

Now iterate over the file again and skip those indexes that are present in that set:

```
f = open('abc')
f1 = open('out.txt', 'w')
for i,x in enumerate(f):
    if i not in se:
        f1.write(x)
f.close()
f1.cose()
```

input file:

```
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 0
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
 *--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
            UTC Time: 000000.00
           Latitude: 0000.0000
            N/S ind.: N
           Longitude: 0000.0000
         E/W ind: E
    Position fix ind: 5
     Satellites Used: 3
        MSL Altitude: 00.0
*--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
```

**output:**

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
1
2
3
*--------------------------------------*
UTC Time: 000000.00
Latitude: 0000.0000
N/S ind.: N
Longitude: 0000.0000
E/W ind: E
Position fix ind: 5
Satellites Used: 3
MSL Altitude: 00.0
*--------------------------------------*
3
2
1
```

Comment: Was `with` part of python 2.5 (it's been a while since I've switched to 2.7)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: If you do `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Docs say it was introduced in py2.5 only. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt

Comment: >>> C:/Users/*****/Documents/answer2.py:1: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

Comment: @user2345223 script stops after the warning?

Comment: @user2345223 I've updated my solution, now it should work in your python version too.

Answer (score 0):

If the files aren't too large:

```
 import re
 p = re.compile(r'(?:.*\n){6}\s*Position fix ind: 0\n(?:.*\n){3}')
 with open('test.txt') as f:
    output = p.sub('', f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed what @inspectorG4dget provided and for that I will extend my gratitude. But I needed to do the changes in 2500+ files and to the original files themself. I have added an extra function which handles that. The list.txt contains the name of files  the changes are to be made to and the temp/tempfile is used for writing temporarily.

```
from shutil import copyfile

def remLines(infilepath, outfilepath, delim, above, below):
    infile = open(infilepath)
    outfile = open(outfilepath, 'w')
    buff = []
    line = infile.readline()
    while line:
        if line.strip() == delim:
            buff = []
            for _ in range(below):
                infile.readline() 
        else:
            if len(buff) == above:
                outfile.write(buff[0])
                buff = buff[1:]
            buff.append(line)
        line = infile.readline()
    outfile.write(''.join(buff))


def readfiles(listfilepath, tempfilepath):
    refile = open(listfilepath)
    line = refile.readline()
    while line:
        realfilepath = line.strip()
        remLines(realfilepath, tempfilepath, 'This is test line 17', 2,7)
        copyfile(tempfilepath, realfilepath)
        line = refile.readline()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    readfiles('list.txt', 'temp/tempfile')
```